# Alogrithm for level order traversal using a que and recursion only

Tags: c

my question is how do you perform level-order traversal on a binary tree? I understand you would use a que, but how would I do this recursively? In short I'm trying to print the contents of a tree in level-order as the following:

```
     3
    / \
   2   1
  / \   \
 4   6   10
```

Would print: 3 2 1 4 6 10

I have tried numerous failed attempts which segfault and got frustrated and deleted them. I'm trying to do this using NO loops, only recursion. With loops its not bad but I have started to learn recursion recently and want to finish this method using only recursion. Its just extremely frustrating when you can't get it to work correctly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that recursion is not a good match for this problem.

Comment: @NPE recursion is totally optional for this problem. You can do it with or without it, but the child-queue is critical. The algorithm is pure-tail-recursion so it can easily be done with it, but it can be done with it as well.

Comment: Would be useful if you showed us an example of the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
Traverse (queue, t):
  visit t
  For each child c of t:
      put c to queue
  Traverse (queue, pop queue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this:

```
struct node {
    int isRoot;
    int val;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
};

int printTree(node *root, int level){
    int a = 0,b = 0;
    if(level > 0){
        if(root->left != NULL){
            a = printTree(root->left, level-1);
        }else{ a = 1; }
        if(root->right !=NULL){
            b = printTree(root->right, level-1);
        }else{ b = 1: }
    }else{
        printf("%i", root->val);
        return 0;
    }
    if(isRoot && !(a && b)){
        printTree(root, level+1);
    }
    return a&&b;
}

int main(void){
    //get your tree somehow and put the root into
    //node *head with only the root node having isRoot as true;
    printTree(head, 0);
}
```

btw I'm not sure this will just compile, so consider it pseudo-pseudo-code.

EDIT: updated code to not be so retarded. It goes by levels, first level 0 (`root`), then level 1 (`root->left`, `root->right`) and so on. the `a` and `b` flags signify when a tree pruning (`NULL` node) is hit.

Comment: this is depth first traversal

Comment: also, my solution doesn't use queues; because I hate them.

Comment: i assume you miss `{` after `if(root->left != NULL)`. Anyways i think your code does print only first level (root). Because you call it with level 0 which fails the `if(level > 0){` condition and goes to else, prints the value and returns 0...

Comment: oh, thanks. I was forgetting the step to move to the next level.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do recursion, it would be slower!

Take a look at simple example using a queue in javascript!

```
function leverOrder(root) {
    // Node struct -> { value, left, right }

    if(!root) return;

    var q = [ root ];

    while(q.length) {
       var current = q.shift();

       // do stuff with value
       console.log(current.value);

       if(current.left)  q.push(current.left);
       if(current.right) q.push(current.right);
    }

}
```